# Multiple ENIs on EC2 use case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-network-interface

I created 2 private subnets PRIVATEA and PRIVATEB in a custom VPC. These subnets are in different availability zones. Added an EC2 instance in PRIVATEA. The instance already has an ENI eth0 attached to it. Next I created an ENI in the other PRIVATEB subnet and attached it to EC2 instance in PRIVATEB subnet. The setup is successful. Basically I followed a blog tutorial for this setup. It said that secondary interface will allow traffic for another group i.e. Management.

But I am not able to relate any use case with it. Could anyone please explain when do we use such a setup ? Is this the correct question to ask in this forum here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

An Elastic Network Interface (ENI) is a virtual network card that connects an Amazon EC2 instance to a subnet in an Amazon VPC. In fact, ENIs are also used by Amazon RDS databases, AWS Lambda functions, Amazon Redshift databases and any other resource that connects to a VPC.

Additional ENIs can be attached to an Amazon EC2 instance. These extra ENIs can be attached to different subnets in the same Availability Zone. The operating system can then route traffic out to different ENIs.

Security Groups are actually associated with ENIs (not instances). Thus, different ENIs can have different rules about traffic that goes in/out of an instance.

An example for using multiple ENIs is to create a [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)), which acts as a perimeter through which traffic must pass. For example:

```
Internet --> DMZ --> App Server
```

In this scenario, all traffic must pass through the DMZ, where traffic is typically inspected before being passed onto the server. This **can be implemented by using multiple ENIs**, where one ENI connects to a public subnet to receive traffic and another ENI connects to a private subnet to send traffic. The Network ACLs on the subnets can be configured to disallow traffic passing between the subnets, so that the only way traffic can flow from the public subnet to the private subnet is via the DMZ instance, since it is connected to both subnets.

Another use-case is **software that attaches a license to a MAC address**. Some software products do this because MAC addresses are (meant to be) unique across all networking devices (although some devices allow it to be changed). Thus, they register their software under the MAC address attached to a secondary ENI. If that instance needs to be replaced, the secondary ENI can be moved to another instance without the MAC address changing.

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation for the DMZ setup?  I'm trying to do exactly this, but my EC2 always prefers eth0 for traffic.